# What strategies can I use to avoid 'top-of-list' defaults for non-nullable lookup fields in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have several 'lookup' fields in my models where I don't want nulls, but on Create views it is very inconvenient that these fields keep defaulting to the first value in teh Select lists. What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the dropdown to show something like

```
--select a value--
```

And then throw a validation error if no selection is done.

You can do that by simply specifing a default value in the `Html.DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyValueId, Model.MyValues, "--select a value--")
```

In your model you will have the `RequiredAttribute` or in the controller you do the validation needed